# !the compiler just leaves a stub! ,C++, find these "stubs" in .o file

Tags: c++, assembly, compiler-construction, linker

What I wanted to achieve

> At the time of compilation, the compiler knew the function call was
>   valid because you included the iostream header file, but since that
>   function was not part of the cpp file, **the compiler just leaves a *stub***
>   at the call site. The linker goes through the object file, and for
>   each stub, it finds the correct function address and replaces the stub
>   with the correct address from one of the other object files being
>   linked. **by ALEX ALLAN , Jumping to C++**

In above  the "stub" , I wanted to see in real object files.

What I did as follows,

Code
//main.cpp

```
#include "f.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   myfunc();

    return 0;
}


    //f.cpp
    #include "f.h"
    void myfunc()
    {
    }


 //f.h
#ifndef F_H_INCLUDED
#define F_H_INCLUDED

 void myfunc();

#endif // F_H_INCLUDED
```

above 3 in separate files.

objdump command I used on main.o

```
C:\Users\User\Downloads\binutils-2.22-1-mingw32-bin.tar\binutils-2.22-1-mingw32-
bin\bin>objdump.exe -S -C C:\Users\User\Documents\myC++\testFuncstabs\obj\Debug\
main.o
```

[image]

But now I am stuck at finding "stub" for myFunc in this output?

Could anyone help me on this ? or suggest me another strategy to achieve this goal?

Comment: The stub seems to be the three `call` statements in a row which just call each other.  No idea how that works.

Comment: That's actually a consequence of the x86 instruction encoding - in the final executable, they are redirected to other locations (i.e. other functions).

Answer (score 7):

"Stub" in this context does not mean a small function. Instead, it refers to a small placeholder value. Notice how at hex offsets `109`, `120`, `125` etc. have 4 bytes as zero? That's the stub. When the linker processes the object file, it'll look through a *relocation table* stored elsewhere in the object file. This table includes references to other symbols as well as what parts of code/data use those symbols. Once the linker finds where that symbol is defined, it will replace (aka relocate) those "stub" values to point to the correct address. If you were to view the disassembly of `main` from the actual executable, you would see all those zeros replaced with other values (aka the address (rather, the offset) of the functions, variables etc. that your code uses).

Comment: Using `objdump -dr main.o` will show these relocation records in the disassembly output, making it even clearer how this all works.